# How can I update state after setting it in UseEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, use-effect

I want to display a list of products in one of my components. I need to use UseEffect to get the results of a function that returns a promise. I then am setting state in UseEffect but am having trouble displaying the products. The state is getting updated but I am not able to render the results on the dom.

Here's the component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import pullShopifyData from "../../functions/shopify"

export default function DataPreview(props) 
    const { apiKey } = props

    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        pullShopifyData(apiKey).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.shop.products)
            setData(response.data.shop.products)
        })
      }, [])
    
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            {data.length > 0 ? data.map(product => (
                <ProductWrapper>{product}</ProductWrapper>
            )): <NoProductsWrapper>No Products Found</NoProductsWrapper>}
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

const Wrapper = styled.div``

const ProductWrapper = styled.div``

const NoProductsWrapper = styled.div``
```

Here's the output on the dom:
[image]

Comment: remember that useEffect kicks in [_on every render_](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update) (unless you very specifically told it not to by telling it which vars to ignore), which is why useEffect is generally for side effects, e.g. things that _don't_ affect state. Right now, your render() runs, useEffect kicks in, and so setData() runs, which run render because it's a state update, so your useEffect kicks in, and so setData runs, which ... you get the idea.

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if you have any data?

Comment: Oh, and this is a pretty normal way of loading data. If you want to do it nicer, see @douscriptist's answer. If you want to do it the easy way though, check this out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fetch-hook

Comment: I have the desired data from the console.log(response.data.shop.products) line. When I log the data from the state var named 'data' I get nothing back.

Comment: Also, doesn't the '[]' parameter I have included in useEffect cause the function to only be run once?

Comment: To log `data` you should `useEffect(() => {console.dir(data)}, [data]);`

Comment: Ok, that logged the desired data

Comment: Ok, give the react-fetch-hook a try, it's far more elegant and will probably save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Move your data fetch function in to async wrapper function. Then just call it in useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchSomething();
}, [])

const fetchSomething = async () => {
     const response = await pullShopifyData(apiKey);
     console.log(response.data.shop.products)
     setData(response.data.shop.products)
}
```

Comment: Apart from the syntactic sugar (which is nice btw), how is this any different from the OP's code?

Comment: Once i faced something like this, somehow using then in useEffect did not work for me. (maybe being async of useEffect itself confused something idk.)
It actually seems ok, im not sure if my problem was different but when i just changed structure like this, it basically worked for me.

Comment: Honestly, this is exactly the same as the OP has (but with nicer code)